# Webservice not accepting get request from postman

Tags: java, azure, web-services, azure-web-app-service

I created a java based process on my local machine, published it as a web service and deployed on a linux VM on azure. Opened the required ports and provided private ip 10.0.0.4 as endpoint to host the webservice.

Process which webservice will execute have read/write/execute permissions.

A batch file from webservice is executed to open the rest endpoints to get the requests.

I created another Windows VM on azure within same network as of Linux VM. Both VMs are able to ping each other.

When I send GET request to webservice API , I receive the error

```
Http Error 403:The IP address/hostname is not allowed
```

Alternatively, I hosted the webservice from Windows VM and started the endpoint using localhost, tested on Postman from the same VM and it works smooth.

Problem:
Why postman on Windows VM can't send GET request to webservice on Linux VM?
When I run curl http://10.0.0.4 , I get

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.0.4 port 80: Connection refused
```

I added 10.0.0.4 in /etc/hosts file as:
10.0.0.4

Please help.

Comment: Hi @user3204086, can you specify what web service framework do you use.

Answer (score 0):

- Configure CORS to permit requests from various origins if your web service is accessible via a different domain or port than Postman. To accept requests from Postman, include the proper CORS headers in the response from your web service.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

- Confirm that the IP address of your Windows VM is permitted access to the web service on the Linux VM.
  [image]
- Verify that your web service is set up properly on the Linux VM to listen on the private IP address (10.0.0.4). Make sure the web service is available from within the VM itself and is bound to the proper IP address and port.

> When I send GET request to webservice API , I receive the error.

Just try to test the curl command to check whether the web service is accepting GET requests on the Linux VM itself. **`curl http://localhost`**

- Try and check by changing the port in Linux VM.
  [image]

Comment: I figured it out. the thing I was doing wrong that I haven't whitelisted the ip address of WinVM in one of the parameters file for WebService. After adding the ip, it started working.

Comment: Great to hear, it's essential to properly configure the IP whitelisting or access control settings in your web service to ensure that only trusted and authorized sources can access the service.